# Cannot sign OS X app with Developer ID certificate properly

Tags: xcode, codesign, code-signing-certificate, osx-gatekeeper

I've read almost anything and everything there is about signing Mac Application for distribution outside the Mac App Store.
Basically - I have a valid "Developer ID Application..." certificate (created a new one just in case) and I made sure all other Apple certificates are there and valid.

O set things up in XCode so that my Developer ID Application... certificate is used for code signing in the relase mode and then archive the app.
After archiving - I even do "Validate" and select the proper team. It goes through it's thing and says that it validated everything without issues.
I then export the app using the same team and everything looks fine, but ... I cannot run the app - says that Code sigining is invalid in the crash log and if I do codesign -dv myapp.app it comes back as myapp.app : no signature and TeamIdentifier=not set etc..

I am starting to pull my hair out!

Any suggestions on what to do? This should work right?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out - it may help someone else...

Turns out that I had one of the Apple Intermediate certificates "Developer ID" set to "Always trust". Apparently - this is what was responsible for the issue. Changing it back to "Use system default" fixed the issue.
I wish the validation process in XCode would catch this.

Comment: Is this within Xcode the "always trust" vs "use system default" or somewhere else?